# Decoded video gives different format from encoded one

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavcodec, x264

I am trying to decode a h264 video that I encoded using FFMPEG. The encoder used is **libx264rgb** with a **AV_PIX_FMT_BGR0** pixel format. The encoded video plays well inside ffplay.

When I decode the frames, I obtain a planar pixel format(**AV_PIX_FMT_GBRP**) which is different from the original. Is it normal? If yes is there a way to disable the planar format? (either at encoding or decoding). This would allow me to skip the packing overhead from planar at runtime.

I used [this decoder sample](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/decode_video.c) with a **AV_CODEC_ID_H264** decoder instead of **AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO**.

Thank you!

Comment: Before decoding, check with ffprobe the h264 video you have, it will give you the original pixel format. This is normally what you get.